# First-order correlation function - Simple example

Tags: quantum-optics, correlation-functions

I am trying to figure out whether the superposition of two stable monochromatic waves is coherent everywhere, and while I expect that to be the case my calculation doesn't show that to be always true. Can you identify any errors in my calculation?

Consider the electric field to be given by
$E\left( t \right)={{E}_{1}}\exp \left( -i{{\omega }_{1}}t \right)+{{E}_{2}}\exp \left( -i{{\omega }_{2}}t \right)$ where the amplitudes and frequencies are constant. Now I try to calculate the normalized first-order correlation function between arbitrary times $t$ and $t+\tau$.

$${{G}^{\left( 1 \right)}}\left( t \right)=\left\langle {{E}^{*}}\left( t \right)E\left( t+\tau  \right) \right\rangle =\left\langle \begin{align}
  & E_{1}^{2}\exp \left( -i{{\omega }_{1}}\tau  \right)+E_{2}^{2}\exp \left( -i{{\omega }_{2}}\tau  \right)+ \\ 
 & {{E}_{1}}{{E}_{2}}\exp \left( i\left( {{\omega }_{1}}-{{\omega }_{2}} \right)t \right)\exp \left( -i{{\omega }_{2}}\tau  \right)+ \\ 
 & {{E}_{1}}{{E}_{2}}\exp \left( -i\left( {{\omega }_{1}}-{{\omega }_{2}} \right)t \right)\exp \left( -i{{\omega }_{1}}\tau  \right) \\ 
\end{align} \right\rangle .$$

**Q1:** Now the average of the t-dependent harmonic functions is zero over one cycle, but what about over an arbitrary long time? Is it justifiable to assume the last two lines are zero due to statistical averaging?

Assuming the answer to the above question is yes,

${{g}^{\left( 1 \right)}}\left( t \right)=\frac{E_{1}^{2}\exp \left( -i{{\omega }_{1}}\tau  \right)+E_{2}^{2}\exp \left( -i{{\omega }_{2}}\tau  \right)}{E_{1}^{2}+E_{2}^{2}}$

for which $\left| {{g}^{\left( 1 \right)}} \right|$ is not equal to one for arbitrary $\tau$. This is easy to check for ${{E}_{1}}={{E}_{2}}={{E}_{0}}$ where

$\left| {{g}^{\left( 1 \right)}} \right|=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left\{ 1+\cos \left[ \left( {{\omega }_{1}}-{{\omega }_{2}} \right)\tau  \right] \right\}}=\cos \left[ \frac{1}{2}\left( {{\omega }_{1}}-{{\omega }_{2}} \right)\tau  \right]$

which can be anywhere between zero and one for different values of $\tau$.

**Q2:** So what am I missing here? The superposition I started with is a beat note which I expect to be coherent for arbitrary $\tau$ while my result doesn't agree with that.

I appreciate your comments.

**p.s.** This problem is identical to a problem in Loudon's Quantum Theory of Light which is problem 3.2. It asks to prove that a light beam with electric field given by $E\left( t \right)={{E}_{1}}\exp \left( i{{k}_{1}}z-i{{\omega }_{1}}t \right)+{{E}_{2}}\exp \left( i{{k}_{2}}z-i{{\omega }_{2}}t \right)$ with constant amplitudes is coherent for all pairs of points $\left( {{z}_{1}},{{t}_{1}} \right)$ and $\left( {{z}_{2}},{{t}_{2}} \right)$. I plug these in the definition of correlation function and again I readily get the exact same expression for ${{g}^{\left( 1 \right)}}\left( \tau  \right)$ as above with $\tau ={{t}_{2}}-{{t}_{1}}-\frac{{{z}_{2}}-{{z}_{1}}}{c}$. To my surprise, the subsequent problem asks to show that this expression is the answer assuming random amplitudes and random phases instead of constant amplitudes and identical time-independent phases as above when the average intensity is evenly distributed between the two modes.